# Proof regarding a function that is continuous and discontinuous on different domains.

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

[image]

I'm looking for feedback on my proof, as I am sure that there is something I've missed that can render the entire thing false. The whole topic of discontinuity and stuff I can and cannot use is really confusing to me and I'd love to hear some tips for my future proofs in general.. Of course if there is something I did wrong, or is inaccurate in my proof I'd love to hear it!

Note that D(x) is the Dirichlet function.

Consider the function $f: R➜R$,    $\ f\left(x\right)\ =\ \sin\pi x\  \cdot\ D\left(x\right)$.

First we prove f is continuous at every $x ∈ Z$. Note that $\sin\pi x\  = 0$ for every $x ∈ Z$, and is continuous at every $x ∈ R$.

Let $x_{0}$ ∈ Z. Since D(x) is bounded, and since

$\lim \:_{x\to \:x_{0}}\sin \pi \:x=\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:x_{0}}\sin \:\pi  \:\:x_{0}=0$

Then by "Bounded x Vanishing" we have

$\lim _{x\to x_{0}}\left(\sin \left(\pi \:x\right)\:\cdot  D\left(x\right)\right)=\left(\sin \:\left(\pi \:\:x_{0}\right)\:\cdot  \:D\left(x_{0}\right)\right)=0\ \cdot\ 1 = 0$

Therefore f is continuous at every $x ∈ Z$

Now we prove f is discontinuous at every $x ∈ R/Z$.

Note that $\sin\pi x\ ≠ 0$ for every $x ∈ R/Z$.

We have previously proven that a function of the sort $g: R➜R$, $\  g=f\cdot D$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ and
$f(x_{0}) = 0$.

Since in our case we can replace $f$ with $\sin\pi x\ $, as it is
continuous on every $x ∈ R$, and we know that $\sin\pi x\ ≠ 0$ for
every $x ∈ R/Z$, then our function cannot be continuous at any $x_{0} ∈  R/Z$, and therefore is discontinuous at every $x_{0} ∈ R/Z$.

Comment: What is the function $D(x)$?

Comment: Dirichlet function. :)

Comment: Would be good that you state it in the question...

Comment: Thanks I added it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did looks correct.

However the "most difficult" part of the proof lies in the sentence *We have previously proven that a function of the sort $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $\
 g=f\cdot D$ is continuous on $a$ if and only if $f$ is continuous and
$f(a) = 0$* which is not provided here.

And by the way a better sentence would be *a real $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $\
 g=f\cdot D$ is continuous at $a$ if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and
$f(a) = 0$*. **The continuity of $f$ for $b \neq a$ is irrelevant for the continuity of $g$ at $a$.**

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! This is the previous proof

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965762/proof-regarding-continuouity-and-the-derichle-function